# How to insert a Twitter post in simple HTML page using only the Twitter ID

Tags: twitter

I am having only the Twitter post ID. How to insert a Twitter post in simple html page using only the twitter ID.

(Eg: Twitter post ID is 495719809695621121).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three steps to achieve:

- Integrate official widget script for embedding twits into your web-page

```html
<head>
  <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
```

- Construct link for required twit from this template: `https://twitter.com/i/status/{status-id}`
- Add `<blockquote>` tag with class `twitter-tweet` and link `<a href="{link-above}"></a>` inside your page body.

```html
<body>
  <blockquote class="twitter-tweet">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/i/status/495719809695621121"></a>
  </blockquote>
</body>
```

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/9uszkxe1/